# Contar total de arrays em Javascript:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]  
[Object, Object, Object, Object]  
[Object, Object, Object, Object]  
[Object, Object, Object, Object]  
[Object, Object, Object, Object]  
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Tem vários `arrays` em uma página e preciso contá-los. ***Atenção:*** Não quero usar o `length` para saber quantos itens tem em cada `array` e sim saber quantos `arrays` tem a todo.

Por exemplo, na lista acima me retornaria o número 6 (total de `arrays`).
tenho um array fixo de teste:

```
$scope.tickets = [{
    name: 'Pista Inteira - Lote 01',
    items: [{
      type: 'Homem',
      value: '100,00',
      quantity: 0
    }, {
      type: 'Mulher',
      value: '80,00',
      quantity: 0
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Pista (PNE)',
    items: [{
      type: 'Homem',
      value: '100,00',
      quantity: 0
    }, {
      type: 'Mulher',
      value: '80,00',
      quantity: 0
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Camarote',
    items: [{
      type: 'Homem',
      value: '100,00',
      quantity: 0
    }, {
      type: 'Mulher',
      value: '80,00',
      quantity: 0
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Lounge',
    items: [{
      type: 'Homem',
      value: '100,00',
      quantity: 0
    }, {
      type: 'Mulher',
      value: '80,00',
      quantity: 0
    }]
  },
];
```

Eu gero esse array várias vezes e gostaria de contar quantos vezes esse array foi gerado.

Alguém sabe me dizer como faço isso?

Comment: tem o exemplo desse conjunto de `arrays`?

Comment: E onde estão esses *array* na página? De onde vem esses *array*?

Comment: vou editar a pergunta

Comment: você quer a quantidade de arrays dentro de cada chave `items`?

Comment: Como essas arrays são geradas? Qualquer coisa encapsule elas em uma outra array usando `push` e pegue o length dela

Comment: Não vejo vários arrays, vejo um array de objetos que contém array.

Comment: @EdinhoRodrigues a soluções proposta alguma te serviu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.countItems = function()
  {
      $scope.count = 0;
      angular.forEach($scope.tickets, function(a){
         $scope.count += a.items.length;  
      });      
  }
  $scope.tickets = [{
      name: 'Pista Inteira - Lote 01',
      items: [{
        type: 'Homem',
        value: '100,00',
        quantity: 0
      }, {
        type: 'Mulher',
        value: '80,00',
        quantity: 0
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Pista (PNE)',
      items: [{
        type: 'Homem',
        value: '100,00',
        quantity: 0
      }, {
        type: 'Mulher',
        value: '80,00',
        quantity: 0
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Camarote',
      items: [{
        type: 'Homem',
        value: '100,00',
        quantity: 0
      }, {
        type: 'Mulher',
        value: '80,00',
        quantity: 0
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Lounge',
      items: [{
        type: 'Homem',
        value: '100,00',
        quantity: 0
      }, {
        type: 'Mulher',
        value: '80,00',
        quantity: 0
      }]
    },
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<button ng-click="countItems()">Clicar</button>
<div>{{count}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa solução abaixo usa uma função recursiva e vai checando as propriedades de cada objeto. Se passar valores primitivos no `for... in` vai dar um estouro de pilha com as strings (porque ao mínimo no ECMAScript 5 existe getter para ler cada caractere, como para ler cada item de uma array).

P.S.: aqui contou 5 do total, e aparenta ser.

```
// Quantidade de `Array`'s contadas.
var amount = 0;

function count(value) {
    var k;

    if (typeof value === 'object') {

        if (value instanceof Array) {
            // ou: value.constructor === Array
            ++amount;
        }

        for (k in value) {
            count(value[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Sobre a condição de verificar se o valor é uma array... `instanceof` vai funcionar com classes que herdam `Array`.